# Sed: capture the text between the first ( and )

Tags: sed

I have the following badly formatted text:

```
<h1 id="page-title">ABCD TEXT TEXT ( QQQ-10-123-01)</h1>
<h1 id="page-title">ABCD TEXT TEXT (QQQ-10-123-02)</h1>
<h1 id="page-title">ABCD TEXT TEXT (QQQ-10-123-03 (QWERTY))</h1>
```

and need to get from it:

```
QQQ-10-123-01
QQQ-10-123-02
QQQ-10-123-03 (QWERTY)
```

I.e. get only text between the first "*(*" and "*)*", at the moment doing the following:

`sed -n "s/.*<h1 id=\"page-title\">.*(\(.*\))<\/h1>.*/\1/p" ./file.txt`

and get:

```
 QQQ-10-123-01
QQQ-10-123-02
QWERTY)
```

As you can see only the second line is being processed properly, since this line is most accurate. There are problems with ignoring possible whitespace and dealing with double entry "*(*" and "*)*". Can somebody give the right direction for solving the problems?

P.S. I need to parse over 2k lines; would there be a big difference in performance between `sed` and `awk`? As far as I have been reading and understood, `sed` should have a little benefit in speed. Is that really so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/[^(]*([[:space:]]\?\([^)]*)\?\)).*/\1/' input_file
QQQ-10-123-01
QQQ-10-123-02
QQQ-10-123-03 (QWERTY)
```

```
$ sed -E 's/[^(]*\([[:space:]]?([^)]*\)?)\).*/\1/' input_file
QQQ-10-123-01
QQQ-10-123-02
QQQ-10-123-03 (QWERTY)
```

Comment: hm, interesting; I get the original, unprocessed strings. Using BSD sed, in GNU sed it actually works.

Comment: @KarlsD That's because `\?` is a GNU sed extension to basic regular expressions. Using the `-E` flag and an unescaped `?` might work, or the more portable `\{0,1\}`.

Answer (score 1):

Using any sed:

```
$ sed 's/[^(]*( *\(.*\)).*/\1/g' file
QQQ-10-123-01
QQQ-10-123-02
QQQ-10-123-03 (QWERTY)
```